# Are postgresql RAISE messages stored somewhere?

Tags: postgresql, message, raise, info

Specifically I want to see if I can retrieve RAISE INFO messages that I use to see progress in the console.

Are these stored somewhere in pg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not necessarily](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html):

> Whether messages of a particular priority are reported to the client,
>   written to the server log, or both is controlled by the
>   log_min_messages and client_min_messages configuration variables.